# java cannot retrieve array objects from other class

Tags: java, arrays

I'm doing something wrong and can't get it figured out. I have an array of texture regions. I initialize the array in the constructor with elements from another texture region array in another class. This works fine.

Then in my update method I want to replace the objects in the array with different random ones from the array in the other class. This fails with a null pointer exception. Anyone can push me in the right direction? Code below.

```
Level1 lvl1 = new Level1();
//initialize local array with objects from array in lvl1
shapes = new TextureRegion[4];
txt1 = new TextureRegion(lvl1.shapes[0]);
txt2 = new TextureRegion(lvl1.shapes[1]);
txt3 = new TextureRegion(lvl1.shapes[2]);
txt4 = new TextureRegion(lvl1.shapes[3]);
shapes[0] = txt1;
shapes[1] = txt2;
shapes[2] = txt3;
shapes[3] = txt4;
```

The above works. Then the update method:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {

    int rnd = random.nextInt(15);
    System.out.println(rnd);

    shapes[x] = lvl1.shapes[0];
}
```

This generates a null pointer exception. For testing purposes i just try to access the first object. The 0 should be replaced by `rnd` later.

Comment: It would be helpful if you specify in which methods the code snippets you posted appear, and where you declare all the variables used in those methods.

Comment: As @Eran wrote - you have some problem with variables declaration. Possible that you work with variables in different visibility scopes. May you provide code where you create this variable? Is this code fragments is single function? Is it is single function - it would be better if you provide full function body (without parts that don't in touch with Level1 objects) - it is necessary to understand function body structure. If it is different functions - the same option for full class body.

Comment: `shapes[x] = lvl1.shapes[0];`  Never do this. Never invoke any method on an object without checking if that object is null or not; otherwise you get the deadly run time exception - here its null pointer exception. In your case `lvl1` is null. Read about `stack` , `local variables` in Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I have solved the issue immediatly after posting this. I had to change the Aray in the lvl1 class to Static. Then it works.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the problem is here :

```
Level1 lvl1 = new Level1();
```

You initialize a local variable in the constructor, and in the update method you are accessing an uninitialized instance variable (`lvl1.shapes[0]1`), which throws `NullPointerException`.

Change it to :

```
lvl1 = new Level1();
```

in order to initialize the instance variable.